# How to pass props to {props.children} in NextJS, Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have an issue to pass props from the parent component into my children components, ok let see the code below

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Nav from "./Nav";

const GlobalStyle: any = createGlobalStyle`
    body {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        font-family: 'Comic sans MS'
    }
`;

export default function Layout(props) {
    let [pages, setPages] = useState(null) //1. the props i want to pass
    const Children = props.children
    return (
        <>
            <GlobalStyle />
            <Nav />
            {Children} {/*2.the target*/}
            <Footer />
        </>
    )
}
```

The code above is saved as Layout.tsx, I wanted to pass `let [pages, setPages] = useState(null)` into `{Children}`. And i call the Layout component in _app.tsx below

```
import Router from 'next/router';
import Layout from '../components/Layout';
import NProgress from 'nprogress';
import 'nprogress/nprogress.css';

Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', () => NProgress.start());
Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', () => NProgress.done());
Router.events.on('routeChangeError', () => NProgress.done());

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
    )
}
```

The target children is my index pages named index.tsx, and i can't find a way to pass the props into it, below is my directory tree

```
|- components
|  |- Layout.tsx
|
|- pages
|  |- _app.tsx
|  |- index.tsx
```

maybe anyone can help my issue here, thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why `[pages, setPages]` needs to be in `Layout`? Could you not move that to `_app` and pass it within `pageProps` directly to `Component`?

Comment: aah, it's good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i create state on `_app.tsx` and pass it to `index.tsx` and `layout.tsx` so i can access the value from both.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how dynamic routing works in Next App Router:

e.g. your browser url is: localhost:3000/products/2

This can be structured like this:

- app

  - products

    - [page]

      - page.tsx

Then in your page.tsx do something like:

```
export default async function ProductPage({ params } : { params: { slug: string }}) {
  const { slug } = params
  const product = await fetch(`product/${slug}`) // do some data fetching...
  
  return (
    <div>{product.name}</div>
  )
}
```

For more information read about dynamic routing:

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes